# Error "resource Punkt not found" when deploying Python Flask with nltk to gcp

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, nltk

I'm trying to deploy my Python Flask app to Google Cloud. It runs fine on my local machine but I get an error when deploying to the cloud. I get "Resource punkt not found". From what I can see, I've set the NLTK_DATA variable to be the correct path. It even shows that nltk is looking in that directory for the punkt folder. I'm deploying with App Engine on Google. Using textblob/nltk for sentiment analysis. The error I'm getting is "textblob.exceptions.MissingCorpusError". I'm stuck now so turning to you guys for help.

[env variables and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgmr8.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8s6l.png)

Comment: What are you using to deploy? App engine? Kubernetes? Deployment Manager?

Comment: Ah I left that bit out. Deploying with App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

After trying for hours I finally resolved it. I downloaded the nltk directory manually from [here](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/), put it in the correct place (has to be where your app.yaml file is) and added the variable path to the app.yaml to be `NLTK_DATA: './nltk_data'`

[app.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8rEL.png)